# Calculating a class parameter using a super method

Tags: python, inheritance, parameter-passing, superclass

I am new to Python and trying to understand what is the most correct way to do the following:

I have a base class called "Sample". It has some properties such as dp, tp, etc.

I also have several subclasses derived from this base as SampleA, SampleB, etc. They have several properties which distinct one from another. One of the properties is computed using these distinctive properties. And this calculation is quite repetitive, therefore I want to write one method and call it in every class to compute the value of the parameter.

```
class Sample(object):
    tp = 4
    dp = 4.2
    por = 0.007

    def common_method(self, arg1, arg2)
        return self.tp - arg1 * arg2

class SampleA(Sample)
    arg1 = 0.1
    arg2 = 2
    # I want to calculate arg3, but I don't know how to call the         
    # common_method here.

class SampleB(Sample)

.
.
.
```

I looked it up before asking the question but I did not see a similar question.

Thank you vert much in advance.

Comment: `common_method()` needs an object, but you are still in the class declaration. Has `common_method()` any other use? Because then you could just make it a [class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) and refer to it by `Sample.common_method()`.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @dhke I consider using common_method only within the class.

Comment: @Jared It's for Python 3

Comment: `arg3 = Sample().common_method(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: @Goyo I tried that but it does not work.

Comment: @dhke Thanks a lot, it worked!

Comment: @mutotemiz Works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is suggested by [dhke](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) in the comments of the original question:

> `common_method()` needs an object, but you are still in the class declaration. Has `common_method()` any other use? Because then you could just make it a [class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) and refer to it by `Sample.common_method()`

Applying it into the code would be better, I think:

```
class Sample(object):
    tp = 4
    dp = 4.2
    por = 0.007

@classmethod
def common_method(self, arg1, arg2)
    return self.tp - arg1 * arg2

class SampleA(Sample)
    arg1 = 0.1
    arg2 = 2
    arg3 = Sample.common_method(arg1, arg2)  # 3.8

class SampleB(Sample):

.
.
.
```

Thank you very much for helping me with this!

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of those rare instances where a metaclass makes sense.

```
class CommonProperty(type):
    @property
    def common_property(cls):
        return cls.tp - cls.arg1 * cls.arg2

class Sample(object, metaclass=CommonProperty):
    tp = 4

class SampleA(Sample):
    arg1 = 0.2
    arg2 = 2

print(SampleA.common_property) # 3.6
```

The idea is to assign a `property` onto the metaclass that is inherited and completed by the subclasses. A metaclass is natural here because the goal is to create a class `property` rather than an instance `property` and a class is an instance of a metaclass.